# .NET C# Service running behind OpenVPN doesn't return the correct public IP

Tags: c#, networking, service, vpn, openvpn

So the goal of this service is to determine if the machine is on a known network such as different office locations or not based on the public IP. I've created a few lists of known IP addresses to compare against. If the public IP is not known, I trigger a process to start an OpenVPN connection to my server.

I have been utilizing `http://ipv4.icanhazip.com` for retrieving the public IP.

The current behavior is, during the first Timer interval the web request returns the correct public IP. The VPN connection is then called and shortly establishes. In `CMD` I am able to run `curl http://ipv4.icanhazip.com` and confirm the VPN server IP as well the IPv4 route table has in fact been updated. All my web browser traffic is being routed correctly.

However the service requests never return the new IP during the 15 second intervals.

Here is my WebRequest function

```cs
 public static string ReturnPublicIP()
        {
            string url = "http://ipv4.icanhazip.com";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd().Trim((char)0x0a, (char)0x0d);
            }
        }
```

Any idea's on what I can do to remedy this? I would imagine the networking\process thread would be aware of the updated route table and flow the traffic accordingly..

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Tips: 1) `(char)0x0d` is same as `'\r'`, `(char)0x0a` is same as `'\n'`. 2) `Trim()` removes redundant lines by default, thus simple `Trim()` call without any arguments is enough in your case.

Comment: Try the example below. Is public IP attached to local interface or it's on remote router? If local, try receive local network interface config instead of asking remote service or connect via telnet/ssh to the router to obtain it.